# Server code in *.server.ts getting bundled in Remix JS Client

Tags: prisma, remix

I am building a Remix JS / Prisma app, following the [Remix Jokes App tutorial](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/tutorials/jokes#auth-flow-overview) by Kent C Dodds.

I am getting an error that says:

```
PrismaClient is unable to be run in the browser.
```

even though `PrismaClient` is being run inside a `*.server.ts` file which means the Remix compiler should be excluding it from the client bundle.

**Here is my route file:**

```js
// app/routes/auth/login.tsx

import {
  type ActionFunction,
  json
} from "@remix-run/cloudflare";
import LoginScreen from "~/screens/LoginScreen"
import { login } from "~/utils/session.server"; // Import from .server file
import { useActionData } from "@remix-run/react";


const badRequest = (data: ActionData) =>
  json(data, { status: 400 });

export const action: ActionFunction = async ({
  request,
}) => {
  // Get and validate input [Omitted]

  const user = await login({ email, password }); // <-- Problematic code path
  if (!user) {
   return badRequest({
     fields,
     formError: `Incorrect username or password.`,
   });
  }
  // Redirect user into the app [Omitted]
}

export const loader = () => null;

export default function LoginRoute() {
  const data = useActionData();
  return (
    <LoginScreen formError={data?.formError} fieldErrors={data?.fieldErrors}/>
  )
}
```

**Here is my `session.server.ts` file, where I define the `login` function:**

```js
// app/utils/session.server.ts

import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import { db } from "./db.server";

export async function login({
  email,
  password,
}) {
  const user = await db.user.findUnique({ where: { email } }); // <-- Problematic code path

  if (!user) return null;
  const isCorrectPassword = await bcrypt.compare(
    password,
    user.passwordHash
  );
  if (!isCorrectPassword) return null;
  return { id: user.id, email };
}
```

**Here is where I defined `PrimsaClient`:**

```js
// app/utils/db.server.ts

import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

let db: PrismaClient;

declare global {
  var __db: PrismaClient | undefined;
}

// This is needed because in development we don't want to restart
// the server with every change, but we want to make sure we don't
// create a new connection to the DB with every change either.
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  db = new PrismaClient();
} else {
  if (!global.__db) {
    global.__db = new PrismaClient(); <-- This is where the exception is happening
  }
  db = global.__db;
}

export { db };
```

Why is Primsa being run in the client given that it's inside `*.server.ts`?

Comment: Have you seen this [comment](https://github.com/remix-run/remix/issues/667#issuecomment-997062361) on the remix issues repo on this same problem?